# How to cast BindingSource to DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting, datatables, bindingsource

I am using DataTable to fill in information on my DataGridView. Then, I used BindingSource to filter data on it using:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dgvAppList.DataSource;
bs.Filter = ""; //some filter commands here
dgvAppList.DataSource = bs;
```

Now, after filtering, I want to store the data from my DataGridView on a DataTable. I tried using the following code:

```
var bindingSource = (BindingSource)dgvAppList.DataSource;
var table = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource; // error pops out here
```

But I always end up getting the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to
>   type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

How will I cast BindingSource to DataTable to store my DataGridView data on a DataTable variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `DataGridView` to `DataTable` like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = Ctype(dataGridView1.DataSource,DataTable).copy();
```